# Loop first column over multiple columns and print into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, csv

I have a CSV file that has multiple columns (screenshot attached). The first column has the identifier and the remaining columns have names of individuals. I would like to loop the first column over all of the remaining columns and print them in rows by identifier like this:

| Object ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Church RG 001 | Cox, Fay L. |
| Church RG 001 | Schwar, Elaine D. |
| Church RG 001 | Hollenbach, Raymond E. |

I've tried the following code in Python.

```
import csv as csv
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.iteritems = pd.DataFrame.items

df = pd.read_csv("agents.csv")

s=df[df['Object ID']]
df=df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['Object ID']))
df
```

[image: Image of CSV file]

Comment: Do you want the output should be as same as the excel file shown?

Comment: @SuramuthuR, the CSV file is what I am working with. I would like the output to be like the table I created in the description.

Comment: Will you be using the table in Excel or in Python.  The reason I ask is that structuring the data the way you have is an extremely inefficient way of structuring it if you are going to use the data in Python.  Due to the variable number of names per church it would be more efficient in Python (Pandas) to store a list of names in a single 'Names' column.

Comment: @Jamie, I would like the output table to be in excel file format.

Comment: use `df.set_index('Object ID').stack().reset_index()` or use the `melt` mrthod ie `df.melt('Object ID')`

Comment: Use `pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Object ID'])[['Object ID', 'value']]`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with plain python (I mean without pandas)

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        church = row[0]  # Get the church name
        names = row[1:]  # Get the list of names
        
        # Print the church name and each name
        for name in names[1:]:
            print(f'"{church}","{name}"')
```

I used this input file:

```
"church1","name1,a","name1,b","name1,c","name1,d"
"church2","name2,a","name2,b","name2,c","name2,d","name2,e","name2,f"
"church3","name3,a","name3,b"
"church4","name4,a","name4,b","name4,c"
```

and I got this output

```
"church1","name1,b"
"church1","name1,c"
"church1","name1,d"
"church2","name2,b"
"church2","name2,c"
"church2","name2,d"
"church2","name2,e"
"church2","name2,f"
"church3","name3,b"
"church4","name4,b"
"church4","name4,c"
```

Comment: I think that is almost getting me there. It is splitting by the comma. The comma is only separating the last name from the first name and I don't want to split by that.

Comment: Ananth, don't manually split, use the csv modules Reader to actually parse the CSV. @ScottMeyer-Kukan, you should try that, too.

Comment: Thanks @ZachYoung - I have updated
 see the updated answer helps with your output

Comment: @ScottMeyer-Kukan, how does the solution look now?